# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 2 from section 0 which only contains 0 items before the update'

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, uicollectionview

I have a UITextField and an UICollectionView. Based on the characters in the textfield, shouldChangeCharactersInRange called and collectionview reloaded. The app crashed with 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' when user enter characters fast.

Here is my code

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
ItemCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"itemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Item *item = super.itemArray[indexPath.row];
cell.itemName.text = item.name;
cell.detail.text = item.detail;

if (item.image == nil )
{
    NSBlockOperation * op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

        NSData * imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.imageURL]];

        if (imgData == nil)
        {
            UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo1"];
            item.image = image;
        }
        else
        {
            UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            item.image = image;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.itemCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
        });

    }];

    [_itemQueue addOperation:op];
}
else
{
    cell.image.image = item.image;
}

return cell;
}



- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString * searchStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    searchStr = [Validation trim:searchStr];

   [super.itemArray removeAllObjects];

   for (Item *searchItem in _allItemsArray)
   {
      if(!([searchItem.name rangeOfString:searchStr options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound))
      {
         [super.itemArray addObject:searchItem];
      }
   }

   [_itemCollectionView reloadData];

   return TRUE;

}
```

This works fine when user enter the characters slowly but when user enter the text fast, it crashes with exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 2 from section 0 which only contains 0 items before the update'.

It seems like it is deleting the row twice. What would be the possible solution?

Comment: `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is the last place you should be making any attempt to update the collection view.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve so we can suggest the proper way to do it. Your code is not too meaningful as it is at the moment. All I can say is the same as what @rmaddy said: having removeAllObjects() and reloadData()  in shouldChangeCharactersInRange() sounds fishy

Comment: @pnizzle You mean `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, not `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

Comment: @rmaddy `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is actually fine, given that an items image will never come back as nil after an attempt to load it through that NSOperation, otherwise `dataWithContentsOfURL()` will continuously get called for that item(s).

Comment: @pnizzle I am trying to implement search functionality. User enter the name of the item in the text field, based on that I am showing the similar items in the collection view. For that, I have two arrays, allItemArray and itemArray. Text from the textfield is compared with the data in allItemArray and if it matches then added to itemArray which is used to populate the collection view. So whenever the text in the textfield changes,  `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method gets called and the new list of items appear in the collection view.